# What are the differences between Earliest Deadline First (EDF) and Earliest Due Date (EDD)?

Tags: computer-architecture, scheduling, cpu, process-scheduling, threads

From my understanding, the EDF (Earliest Deadline First) rule is essentially an iterative "version" of the EDD (Earliest Due Date) rule, which allows for preemption. At every point in time, EDF looks at all the processes present and sorts them into the processes with the earliest deadlines first and the latest deadlines the last.

This means that if at time `t1` we only have a process `P1` with deadline `d1` running, and no other processes; then `P1` will run. But if at `t2` we have a new process `P2` with deadline `d2` (such that `d1 > d2`), then `P1` will be interrupted and `P2` will be executed. Once `P2` is finished, if only `P1` is present then it is executed otherwise the deadlines of `P1` and the next process are compared and the one with the earliest deadline is executed.

Is this the only difference or any there any more?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right. In fact I think we can say that EDD is a special case of EDF, where all the processes have arrived at the same time.